# Run python script from within c++, modules not found

Tags: python, c++, pip, exec

OSX 10.12

I'm trying to launch a python script that I made from within c using the `execlp()` call (in a forked thread). I can run the script just fine via command line but from the app I get an error saying it can't find the modules. I even tried installing the modules globally, for example `sudo -H pip install requests` but the modules still can't be found. My python script imports the modules as usual:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = requests.get('https://www.douyu.com/directory/all').text
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
urls = soup.select('.play-list-link')

output = '';
output += '[' #open json array
for i, url in enumerate(urls):
    channelName = str(i);
    channelUrl = 'http://douyu.com' + url.get('href')
    output += '{'
    output += '\"channelName\":' + '\"' + channelName.encode('utf-8') + '\",'
    output += '\"channelUrl\":' + '\"' + channelUrl.encode('utf-8') + '\"'
    output += '},'

output = output[:-1] # remove last comma
output += ']' # close json array

print output
```

My execution from my c++ app looks like this (the `execlp()` line is really all I'm showing you here):

```
int pid = fork();
switch(pid){
    case -1:{
        perror("fork");
        _exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        break;
    }
    case 0:{ // child process

    // create output file
        int out = creat(jsonFilePath.c_str(), S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR | S_IRGRP | S_IROTH);
        if (out == -1){ //if failed to create output file, terminate child process
            perror("creat");
            _exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        } else {
            dup2(out,STDOUT_FILENO); // redirect stdout to output file
            execlp("python","python",pythonScript.c_str(), NULL); // exec the command
            close(out); // close output file
            _exit(0); //exit child process
        }
        break;
    }
    default:{
        // wait for child process
        int status = 0;
        waitpid(-1, &status, WNOHANG);
        printf("child status:%d\n",status);
        break;
    }
 }
forkOnce_getJson = true;
```

How can the modules be discoverable by other apps, if not globally at least outside the virtualenv? Thanks in advance!!

Comment: I notice you don’t have a shebang line on the script, so presumably you’re executing the Python interpreter and passing the script as an argument.. Are you sure you’re `exec`ing the right interpreter (assuming you have two or more Pythons installed)?

Comment: `execlp("/usr/bin/python","/usr/bin/python",pythonScript.c_str(), NULL);` works the same as just calling `python` without a full path, and doing `#!/usr/bin/python` will not return any error/response in the console, seems like that's just an erroneous path name.

Comment: My first suspicion is that you have a second Python 2.7 in addition to the Apple pre-installed one, and you’ve setup your bash profile to make sure that’s higher on the PATH than `/usr/bin/python` in the shell, but if you run the program as another user, or as the same user but via Finder or launchd, it’s not getting your profile settings, so it’s running `/usr/bin/python` instead of the one you want. Do you know how to test for that?

Comment: That can’t be an erroneous pathname on macOS; Apple preinstalls Python 2.7 in that location, and in 10.12 and later you can’t even accidentally delete it (without disabling SPI, which I doubt you’ve done).

Comment: I got it! Just checked `which python` in terminal which returned `usr/local/bin/python` so I just copypasted that into the `execlp()` command and that did the trick. Thanks a lot @abarnert

Answer (score 0):

As @abarnert noted in the comments above, I was using the wrong PATH. The correct python version I should have been executing from my cpp program was at `usr/local/bin/python`.